# Can we split solid ionic compounds into their constituent ions when writing an ionic equation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The equation for the reaction between magnesium and copper(II) oxide is:
$$\ce{Mg + CuO -> MgO + Cu}$$
Here, we can write the net ionic equation as:
$$\ce{Mg + Cu^{2+} -> Mg^{2+} + Cu}$$
The $\ce{CuO}$ here is a solid, so why can we still separate it into its constituent ions?
In a neutralization reaction, if the base is a solid then we cannot split it into its constituent ions (as far as I know). For example, the net ionic equation for the reaction between copper(II) oxide and sulfuric acid is:
$$\ce{CuO + 2H+ -> Cu^{2+} + H2O}$$
So why are the rules different in the two reactions? Why can we split the $\ce{CuO}$ into its constituent ions in one reaction but not the other?

Comment: You may find useful these links for text formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: For solid phase reactions, using ionic form of equations is very unusual. It makes more sense if cations and anions move and react independently, like for dissolved or melted salts.  It is rather $\ce{2 CuO <=> 2 Cu + O2}$ and $\ce{2 Mg + O2 <=> 2 MgO}$. Additionally there is lot of covalent character of bonds in these oxides.

Comment: We may formally split in both cases, but it makes little sense.

Comment: @Glorfindel In my experience with mhchem, {} in ion charge is not necessary, as `$\ce{Cu^2+}$`  $\ce{Cu^2+}$  is displayed the same as `$\ce{Cu^{2+}}$` $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$. Not sure, if there is preferred the way with or without {}.

Comment: P.S.: Checked with all renderers but not available MathML and displaying of both is the same. I do agree it would be different for general MathJax.